# Filter query by length of nested objects. ie. min_child

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter my query by the number of nested objects found. The Elastic Search documentation mentions that using a script is an expensive task, so I've set out to do it with a score, though I can't seem to get the script to work either.

**Here's my mappings:**

```json
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "dates" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "properties" : {
        "rooms" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    },
    "doc_id" : {
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "distance" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

**Here's some example data:**

```json
PUT /test/_doc/1
{
  "doc_id": "1",
  "distance": 1,
  "dates": [
    {
      "rooms": 1,
      "timestamp": 1
    },
    {
      "rooms": 1,
      "timestamp": 2
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm filtering by the parents `distance` field, among others, and filtering the nested `dates` by their `timestamps`, and `rooms`. I need to filter all results to an exact number of nest dates found.

I tried to borrow from [here](https://gist.github.com/xethorn/290e31176f493814823a20f281e82fd4).

**This is my search query:**

```json
GET /test/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "function_score": {
      "min_score": 20,
      "boost": 1,
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
                "source": "if (_score > 20) { return - 1; } return _score;"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "filter": [
            { "range": { "distance": { "lt": 5 }}},
            {
              "nested": {
                "score_mode": "sum",
                "boost": 10,
                "path": "dates",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                      { "range": { "dates.rooms": { "gte": 1 } } },
                      { "range": { "dates.timestamp": { "lte": 2 }}},
                      { "range": { "dates.timestamp": { "gte": 1 }}}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns all the results that match, yet they all have a score of 0.0 and aren't getting filtered by the number of nested objects found.

If this is the right solution, how can I get this working? If not, how can I get a script to do it within this search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting started, keep in mind that the scoring function has changed between Elastic 6 and 7. You can find the updated code samples on this [this gist](https://gist.github.com/xethorn/290e31176f493814823a20f281e82fd4).

Your question didn't outline the specifics of your search. Reading the code, it seems like you want to retrieve all documents where the distance is less than five, and the number of matching rooms is precisely 2. If this is correct, the code you submitted does not achieve this.

Reasons: your function score contains your primary condition and your condition on the number of matching rooms (it is quite tricky to mix both, though not impossible). To make things simpler, isolate them for the function score to be only applicable to the number of rooms.

Supposing you are using elastic 7+, this might work:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["*"],
    "excludes": ["dates"]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"range": {"distance": {"lt": 5}}},
        {
          "function_score": {
            "min_score": 20,
            "boost": 1,
            "score_mode": "multiply",
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "if (_score > 20) { return 0; } return _score;"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "date",
                "boost": 10,
                "score_mode": "sum",
                "query": {
                  "constant_score": {
                    "boost": 1,
                    "filter": {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                {"term": {"dates.timestamp": 1}},
                                {"range": {"dates.rooms": {"lt": 5}}}
                              ],
                              "should": [
                                {"term": {"dates.other_prop": 1}},
                                {"term": {"dates.other_prop": 4}}
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                {"term": {"dates.timestamp": 2}},
                                {"range": {"dates.rooms": {"lt": 5}}}
                              ],
                              "should": [
                                {"term": {"dates.other_prop": 1}},
                                {"term": {"dates.other_prop": 3}}
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is so helpful thank you! I actually didn't realise I could nest the function_score like that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it all working with scoring as filtering doesn't allow scoring. Using GET /test/_explain/[id] helped to understand exactly what was happening

```js
GET /test/_search
{
  // Don't return the nested fields, they are returned in the inner_hits
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "dates" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      // Score is calculated with 1 point for each matched inner property and outer property.
      // 7 is the exact score to allow
      "min_score": 7,
      "boost": 1,
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "multiply",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              // Ignore any results that don't match exactly
              "source": "if (_score == 7) { return 1; } return 0;",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            { "range" : { "distance" : { "lt": 10 }}},
            {
              "nested": {
                "inner_hits" : {},
                "path": "dates",
                "score_mode": "sum",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    // Match each required nested object individually, then verify with the score if we got 1 match for each should
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            { "term": { "dates.timestamp": 1 }},
                            { "range": { "dates.rooms": { "lt": 5 } } }
                          ],
                          "should": [
                            { "term": { "dates.other_prop": 1 }},
                            { "term": { "dates.other_prop": 4 }}
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            { "term": { "dates.timestamp": 2 }},
                            { "range": { "dates.rooms": { "lt": 5 } } }
                          ],
                          "should": [
                            { "term": { "dates.other_prop": 1 }},
                            { "term": { "dates.other_prop": 3 }}
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```